# Kong Ingress Controller - How to deploy Kong DB-backed with kong/ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kong

## TL;DR

How can I deploy **Kong DB-backed** with kong/ingress helm chart? Which configuration values I need to set?

## Long Version

I want to try the [Oauth2 plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/oauth2/) which, from the docs, is said to require a Database:

> This plugin requires a database in order to work effectively. It does not work in DB-less or hybrid mode.

Reading the deployment part of the [Kong Ingress Controller documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/3.0.x/#deployment-methods), it's said one can use the kong/ingress helm chart to install Kong both DB-less and DB-backed:

> Kong recommends using the kong/ingress Helm chart to deploy Kong Ingress Controller. **This chart supports both DB-less and DB-backed deployments**.

However, I cannot understand what config parameters I should use to deploy the database pod.

### What I Tried

File `values.yaml`:

```yaml
deployment:
  test:
    enabled: false

controller:
  proxy:
    nameOverride: "{{ .Release.Name }}-gateway-proxy"

  enabled: true

  deployment:
    kong:
      enabled: false

  ingressController:
    enabled: true

    gatewayDiscovery:
      enabled: false
      generateAdminApiService: false

  podAnnotations:
    kuma.io/gateway: enabled
    # This port must match your Kong admin API port. 8444 is the default.
    # If you set gateway.admin.tls.containerPort, change these annotations
    # to use that value.
    traffic.kuma.io/exclude-outbound-ports: "8444"
    traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts: "8444"

gateway:
  enabled: true
  deployment:
    kong:
      enabled: true

  admin:
    enabled: true
    type: ClusterIP
    clusterIP: None

  ingressController:
    enabled: false

  env:
    role: traditional
    database: "postgres"
```

Then I deploy Kong with:

```bash
helm install kong kong/ingress -n kong --create-namespace --values .\test-standard-values.yaml
```

And I wait for pods to be Running and Ready:

```bash
$ kubectl get pods -n kong
kong-controller-549fcc4d84-d5l2f     0/1     Running            0             45s
kong-gateway-5fd66b7498-jh4q6        0/1     Init:1/2           0             45s
kong-gateway-init-migrations-259c6   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2 (21s ago)   45s
```

However, I see that there's no pod for the Postgres database and the kong-gateway-init pod keeps crashing and restarting, with the following logs:

```
Error: [PostgreSQL error] failed to retrieve PostgreSQL server_version_num: connection refused
```

### Question

Can anyone provide me an example with the configuration parameters (of the `values.yaml` file), needed to enable the "DB support"? Or help me understand if there's anything I'm missing or I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You need to pass the database-related environment variables to the values yaml file.
Here are the environment variables which should work for you as well.

```
env:
  database: postgres
  pg_host: postgresql
  pg_user: kong
  pg_password: kong
  admin_gui_path: /
  admin_gui_api_url: /api
```

Add your values in env: section of values yaml as shown above.

Comment: @mikyll98 i have updated my response.